# Can I change my PATH dynamically based on my cwd?

Tags: linux, bash, shell, environment-variables, path

I would like to change my `$PATH` environment variable dependent on my current working directory.

Say I'm in `/foo/bar/baz` and I have the directories `/foo/node_modules/.bin` and `/foo/bar/baz/node_modules/.bin`. I would like to add every possible `./node_modules/.bin` recursively to `$PATH`.

But when I `cd` into a different directory (like `/foo/bar`), I want my original, clean `$PATH` to be restored, and then to start to look for `./node_modules/.bin` recursively again.

(I want to solve my own question from npm's issue tracker: [Can we add locally installed packages to PATH, too?](https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/8221))

Note: I'm on a Mac, but interested in a general solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Introduction

If I understand you correctly, you want to add any directories `"$X/node_modules/.bin"` where `$X` is the `$PWD` or any of its ancestors.

The script at the end of this post should give the behaviour you want. You need to source it in every session where you want it. If you name the file `augment_path.sh`, then adding this line to your `.bashrc` should be sufficient:

```
source augment_path.sh
```

### Discussion

I think garyjohn has the basic approach right, but he's searching all descendents rather than all ancestors.

The `$PROMPT_COMMAND` variable allows you to specify a command to be executed each time the prompt is displayed. I've added a `$PROMPT_COMMAND_OLD` variable to allow the original `$PROMPT_COMMAND` to be restored

It's probably not necessary, but for good form I add a `$LAST_WD` variable and test to avoid recomputing the path when the directory hasn't changed. You can remove all three lines containing `LAST_WD` if you like.

The `augment_path` function scans from `$PWD` upwards, looking for the target directories in each ancestor and adding any it finds to the path.

- They are placed in the path in order, so the deepest such directory will take precedence if there are any conflicts. I assume this is the desired behaviour. If not, change

  ```
  PATH_ADDITION="$PATH_ADDITION:$resolved_target"
  ```

  to

  ```
  PATH_ADDITION="$resolved_target:$PATH_ADDITION"
  ```
- However, these directories will all take precedence over the rest of the path. If you want the rest of the path to take precedence, change:

  ```
  PATH="$PATH_ADDITION:$RAW_PATH"
  ```

  to

  ```
  PATH="$RAW_PATH:$PATH_ADDITION"
  ```

### Script

```
RAW_PATH="$PATH"
LAST_WD=`pwd`

augment_path() {
    target="node_modules/.bin"
    if [ "$PWD" = "$LAST_WD" ]; then return 0; fi;
    PATH_ADDITION=""
    scandir="$PWD"
    until [ "$scandir" = "" ]; do
    resolved_target="$scandir"/"$target"
    if [ -d "$resolved_target" ]; then
        PATH_ADDITION="$PATH_ADDITION:$resolved_target"
    fi
    scandir="${scandir%/*}"
    done 
    PATH="$PATH_ADDITION:$RAW_PATH"
    LAST_WD=`pwd`
}

PROMPT_COMMAND_OLD="${PROMPT_COMMAND%; augment_path}"
PROMPT_COMMAND="$PROMPT_COMMAND_OLD; augment_path"
```

Comment: Thank you every one involved in solving this problem and thank you pyrocrasty for this in-depth answer. As a non-shell-expert your additional explanations are very helpful. Your solution works exactly as I hoped (deepest directory with highest precedence and higher precedence than the rest of the path. Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

You can work with bash's [`PROMPT_COMMAND`](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prompt-HOWTO/x264.html):

```
PROMPT_COMMAND='[ -z "$X" ] && X=$PATH; PATH=$X:$(pwd)/node_modules/.bin'
```

That command is executed every time when the prompt apprears. Therefore, everytime when a command finishes, the `PATH` variable is changed. An additional directory is added to the end.

If there is no directory `./node_modules/.bin` in the current working directory, the path is appended anyway. But, that's not a problem. It is not searched trough (because it doesn't exist).

See the demonstration:

```
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
$ PROMPT_COMMAND='[ -z "$X" ] && X=$PATH; PATH=$X:$(pwd)/node_modules/.bin'
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/node_modules/.bin
$ cd test
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/test/node_modules/.bin
$ cd /etc/
$ echo $PATH
/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/etc/node_modules/.bin
```

Comment: This works nearly as I wanted it, but it doesn't work recursively from the most deep directory to the top or am I doing it wrong? Say I'm in `foo/bar/baz` than no `/foo/bar/baz/node_modules/.bin`and `/foo/node_modules/.bin` are added.

Comment: @Pipo I don't unerstand correctly. Do you want to add 2 folders? So, `./node_modules/.bin` and `../../node_modules/.bin`? If, yes, then use that `PROMPT_COMMAND='[ -z "$X" ] && X=$PATH; PATH=$X:$(pwd)/node_modules/.bin:$(pwd)/../../node_modules/.bin'`. If will look a bit strange i the `$PATH` variable but should work, as desired.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I want to add both folders, because Node modules are nested in each other. Thank you, I'll try that.

Comment: I just noticed that the `../../` part is hardcoded. I'm sorry, I should have said that my `/foo/bar/baz` example is just _one_ example. It could really be _any_ directory structure. I'll try @pyrocrasty 's answer now.

Answer (score 1):

I think putting the following into your `~/.bashrc` will do what you want.

If the bash environment variable `PROMPT_COMMAND` is set to some command, that command is executed before bash displays the primary prompt.

In the code below, `PROMPT_COMMAND` is set to the name of a function, `doit`. That function checks whether the current working directory has changed and if so it first sets `PATH` to its original value, then checks for the presence of a subdirectory named `node_modules/.bin`. If that subdirectory exists, the function appends the names of it and all the subdirectories below it to `PATH`.

`orig_path="$PATH"
prev_pwd=""
doit() {
    if [ "$PWD" != "$prev_pwd" ]; then
        PATH="$orig_path"
        if [ -d "node_modules/.bin" ]; then
            PATH="$PATH$(find $PWD/node_modules/.bin -type d -printf ':%p')"
            # For POSIX compatibility (macOS or other), use:
            # PATH="$PATH$(find $PWD/node_modules/.bin -type d -exec echo -n :{} \;)"
        fi
        prev_pwd="$PWD"
    fi
}
PROMPT_COMMAND=doit`

Comment: I'm sorrty, I forgot to mention that I'm using Mac OS X. It seems I can't use `-printf` there. Besides that I think it should work...

Comment: Replacing `-printf ':%p'` by `-exec echo -n :{} \;` seems to work, too, but not all `echo`s have `-n` and I don't have access to a Mac at the moment. If your `echo` doesn't have `-n` or the equivalent, you could omit the `-n` and follow the `find` with `| tr -d '\n'` to remove the newlines.

Comment: `-n`  seems to work. This works nearly as I wanted it, but it doesn't work recursively from the most deep directory to the top or am I doing it wrong? Say I'm in `foo/bar/baz` than no `/foo/bar/baz/node_modules/.bin`and `/foo/node_modules/.bin` are added.